# Why aren't the values inserted into the mysql2 query?

Tags: node.js

Can you tell me, please?
Why does the mysql2 value substitution not work inside the IN operator?

I do this, but nothing works.
Only the first character of the array is being substituted (number 6)

```
"select * from products_categories WHERE category_id IN (?)", [6,3]);
```

You can do it like this, of course:
IN(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [6,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

But that's not right, I thought that the IN should be automatically substituted from an array =(

Comment: What node package do you use for that?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#first-query

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this, but my gut feeling tells that array items map to question marks based on indexes, so in your case `6` binds to first `?` and `3` looks for another one, but doesn't find.

If I were you, I'd try to make sure that my first array item is then actually array, so I'd rewrite it:

```js
"select * from products_categories WHERE category_id IN (?)", [[6,3]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using this with `.execute()`, which is short for prepared statements "prepare first if never executed before"+execute. While api is very similar to `.query()` one biggest difference is that in case of prepared statement only parameters are sent at execution time, unlike `.query()` where whole query text is interpolated with all parameters on the client. As a result, you need to send exactly the number of parameters as you have number of placeholders in original query text ( in you example - one `?`). The whole `[6,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` is treated as one parameter and sent to server as `"6,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1"` string ( because during prepare step that parameter was likely reported by server as VAR_CHAR )

The solution is 1) use `.query()` and interpolate on the client or 2) build enough `?`s dynamically and prepare different PS for different number of IN parameters